# C++: No Known Conversion from 'FILE *()' to 'FILE *'

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io

I've been trying to remove characters for the middle of a file using a temporary file. However, when I call

```
    fputc(c, tmpfile);
```

where c is a char and tmpfile is a FILE*, I get the following when compiling:

```
dnhobf_fxn.cc:36:7: error: no matching function for call to 'fputc'
      fputc(c, tmpfile);
      ^~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:243:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known
      conversion from 'FILE *()' to 'FILE *' (aka '__sFILE *') for 2nd argument
int      fputc(int, FILE *);
         ^
```

What exactly is the issue here, and how can I rectify it? I am unfamiliar with the difference between a FILE *() and a FILE *.

Comment: Show how you declare `tmpfile`

Comment: Your error is somewhere else.  Listen to your compiler; `tmpfile` is almost certainly *not* a `FILE*`

Comment: Oh... I'm stupid. The instance FILE* was called tmp, not tmpfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your error - the compiler expects a `FILE*`, but you're passing in a `FILE *()` - that is a function taking zero arguments and returning a `FILE*`. Specifically, you're passing in [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile)  function taking zero arguments and returning a `FILE*`.

Presumably you just got the name of your temporary file wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly as stated - one of the arguments was a function pointer (tmpfile) and not actually a FILE*